# what are the risks of using --break-system-packages to force pip3 installation

Tags: pip

error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
install.

```
If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
sure you have python3-full installed.

If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.

See /usr/share/doc/python3.11/README.venv for more information.
```

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.

so I have this error and I want to try and bypass it and forrce the installation by --break-system-packages, what are the risks of forcing the installation?

I tried

```
pip3 install scikitlearn
```

and it gave me the
externally-managed-environment error

Comment: The risk is that, well, you'll break system packages (the ones installed by apt) and packages which depend on them. Future updates may become impossible as well. Such broken Debian is sometimes called "Frankendebian": https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian.  You should follow the advice given by pip, or at very least you should use `pip install --user <package>`, but this also poses a risk of breaking other Python packages installed for your user (in your home directory). But at least this won't destabilize your entire OS.

Comment: Like the message says, use a venv.